# Why was my link-only answer deleted, while other link-only answers still remain?

Tags: discussion

For this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/10104301/773737

Why was my answer deleted?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40048167/773737

I provided a link to a resource, just as other answers did, and mine in particular was deleted, while others answers that linked to resources still remain.

Is there something that I did wrong, that those other link-only answers did right, or are all of the other answers to this question equally deserving of the same deletion that my question faced?

Comment: that links to a site that is riddled with ads and therefor seen as spam

Comment: Looks like it was flagged and the mod found it from there.

Comment: @NathanOliver Flagged for what? Why was it flagged?

Comment: @rene Oh, I have ad-blocker on, so I never noticed any ads. I just saw the useful content

Comment: It entered the LQPQ so it would have to be a VLQ or NAA flag.

Comment: @NathanOliver What do any of those acronyms mean?

Comment: Low Quality Post Queue, Very Low Quality, Not An Answer.

Comment: @yellowantphil What about the other answers to that question which are link-only and still up? Was I just the unlucky one made an example of, or did I do something wrong that the other answers didn't?

Comment: @yellowantphil I don't think there is anything salvageable there  ... delete votes are coming in on the question.

Comment: Yeah, Jon Clements is having a look at it. We don't want to remove value. That is being checked

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there something that I did wrong, that those other link-only answers did right?

Nope, they're all bad, yours just happened to have gotten noticed, because there are tools in place to bring attention to new answers.

Because you have now drawn attention to the other bad answers, they have also been deleted.

Comment: It's a shame that all those resources are now lost from anyone who might have need of them.

Comment: @Houseman People searching for answers to this question can simply find the relevant sources directly, rather than being served a page that links them to where they *actually* want to go.  It's not like the only way to find that content is through the SO post.  But regardless, the point is that this isn't what SO is here to do.  There are lots of things that are very important, or at least useful to someone, that simply doesn't belong on SO; this is one of those things.